# Sequence Pattern recognition with Pybrain

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to use Recurrent Neural networks to classify a series of contiguous data. To be more specific, I have a sequence (that that are continuous in time) of reading from sensors, I need to learn an algorithm that looking at the way the readings change can detect the state related to this pattern.

Example:

Time step_1:  1.4

Time step_2:   1

Time step_3:   0.8

State = Walking. 
New Sequence:

Time step 1:  0.4

Time step 2:   0.3

Time step 3:   0.1

State = sitting

I actually have 12  sensors, I am only showing one sequence of numbers for convenience.
(Numbers are not real, I am just trying to get the idea across) !

I am trying to build my network with Pybrain RNN, However, I can't find a data set container that can detect that kind of information. I tried using SequentialData but after some testing I thing what it it learns is the next element in a sequence of numbers. Here how I build my DataSet:

```
self.alldata = SequentialDataSet(ds.num_features, 1)
# Now add the samples to the data set.
idx = 1 
self.alldata.newSequence()
for sample in ds.all_moves:
  self.alldata.addSample(sample.get_features(), [ds.get_classes().index(sample.class_)])
  idx += 1
  if (idx%6 == 0): #I want every 6 consecutive readings at a time
    pdb.set_trace()
    self.alldata.newSequence()


self.tstdata, self.trndata = self.alldata.splitWithProportion(0.25)
```

Any Ideas on how I can do this differently, Does Pybrain deal with this kind of classification 
Problem anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

## A solution

You could implement this strategy:
[image]

You should probably have 12 sensor inputs plus one extra input which represents the classification from timestep t-1. I've simplified the drawing by only showing 4 inputs.